# Inserting data into sql server fails with no reason

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm quite used to using c# with SQL server. I have no idea why a simple statement would fail to insert data. My code is as follows:

```
 query = "INSERT INTO MCDPhoneNumber ([MCDID],[PhoneNumber])" +
                    "VALUES("+maxid+", '"+tel+"')";
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=source; ...");
 SqlCommand newCommand = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

 int success= myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
 if (success!= 1)
 {
      MessageBox.Show("It didn't insert anything:" + query);
 }
```

First of all let me tell that I know that I should use parameters for data and I initially did, but when it failed I tried a simple query and it still fails. For addition I can tell that I have a similar insert just before that one in another table and it works. What's funnier is that when I copy paste query to SQL Server Management Studio it works. It also doesn't report any error in process.

Comment: Shouldn't you open the connection?

Comment: For the love of all that is holy USE PARAMETERS and not concatenated strings.

Comment: Can you post your real code? I don't see an Open() call on the connection, or using blocks for connection and command.

Comment: Debugging message of the year. Descriptive of more than just the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

====================== Edit ===============================

If you wish to use old command object (i.e. myCommand) then use following code instead of creating a new command(newCommand)

```
 myCommand.CommandText = query;
 myCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
```

And then execute it

you are binding query with **newCommand** and executing **myCommand**.

====================== Edit ===============================

```
SqlCommand newCommand = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
```

here you have defined **newCommand** for SQLCOMMAND object

```
 int success= myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

and you are accessing it as **myCommand**

And moreover i think you are not opening connection

Comment: Yes i used old command instead of new one!! BTW I oppened connection because otherwise it would crash.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you define your command as `newCommand` but you executing your `myCommand`.

You should *always* use [`parameterized queries`](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) for your sql queries. This kind of string concatenations are open for [`SQL Injection`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

```
 query = "INSERT INTO MCDPhoneNumber (MCDID, PhoneNumber) VALUES(@maxid, @tel)";
 using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=source; Initial Catalog=base; Integrated Security = true"))
 {
    SqlCommand newCommand = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    conn.Open();
    newCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@maxid", maxid);
    newCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tel", tel);

    int success= newCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if (success != 1)
    {
         MessageBox.Show("It didn't insert shit:" + query);
    }
 }
```

And please be more polite about your error messages `:)`